# Communication between Spring microservices

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-mvc, microservices

I am still learning microservices and I am asking myself, how do we secure our rest-points? I use the famous framework Spring Boot which extends from Spring. What is the best or most used pattern to secure the endpoints of a rest API?

When I use Spring Security with oAuth2, I always need to send the credentials in the body of the request. Is there an approach without the credentials and which is easier to implement? Like API-Tokens?

I always prefer practical tutorials.

Comment: Have a look at SSL, there are some free SSL providers out there and it will create an encrypted connection between the two endpoints, making the body almost impossible to read.

Comment: oAuth2 supports token authentication. Check JWT tokens support in spring-security/spring boot

Comment: Ah okay, i will look at both suggestions. Maybe i will come back later :) Thx guys.

Comment: You need to learn about Zuul along with spring-cloud-security and with Java Cryptography Extension

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to look into spring security and various options that it provides.
If however you are looking from microservices standpoint, you are on a right path with access tokens and as suggested [JWT](https://jwt.io/) will do good.
No to get a JWT you can opt for another small auth service using say [Pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j) or similar tools out there.

I prefer to use [keycloak](http://www.keycloak.org/) initially
Its a open source IAM
There are several examples that you can find as to how to get started with Keycloak and Spring boot
But here is the [one](https://github.com/XMansion/Kingcross) that I wrote some time back .

--
Just to add that for microservices it makes sense to use AccessTokens as you are not required to keep user creds and pass it along every service and also services can verify the tokens all by themselves without making an expensive network call to your auth service.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose to look at this example (that uses "server" scope): https://github.com/sqshq/PiggyMetrics and for more advanced configuration: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_security